# Inspect packets coming over Linux-based bridge, and run scripts when certain conditions are met

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm attempting to do some research regarding replay attacks on physically insecure devices. I have a Raspberry Pi device set up as a bridge to passively monitor Ethernet activity from a device to the network, in order to determine the protocols and syntaxes used for these devices to communicate with one another and generating PCAPs of known-good responses.

The next step will be for the device to inspect the packets coming over the bridge and, if they match a set of criteria, using a utility akin to `tcpreplay` to replay the known-valid responses from the PCAP files in order to successfully execute a replay attack. Otherwise, the packets should be allowed through the bridge just the same as any others.

Is there a utility that exists for this task in particular?

Comment: Ettercap is used in a similar way. Is that in line with what you're looking for?

Comment: Can ettercap be configured to filter packets coming across a bridged connection? **Edit:** I see ettercap has the `-B`/`--bridge` argument. I'll do some more research on this a little later.